# Samba file sharing working on one windows computer, but not the other

Tags: networking, server, samba

Just like it says in the title, I'm having a problem where one of my windows computers can connect to the samba server, but not the other

I've configured them almost identically, yet nothing seems to work

Both computers can see the server, and i can definitely ping it, but trying to access it just gives me [this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLORR.png)

CRISPYSERVER is the name of my server

the only other problem I've had configuring it was when I figured out I needed to turn on SMB1 in the windows options

I'm at a loss, I've tried everything from updating my network adapters to adding SSH (which works fine on both computers)

any help with this problem would be much appreciated

Comment: It sounds like these Windows computers are running Win10. If that is the case connect to the server directly with its mDNS ( hostname.local ) name: \\crispyserver.local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the answer came really unexpectedly, but basically, i gave up a couple days ago, restarted my computer today, and now it works fine

I'm pretty confused because I made sure to reset my computer before testing it out, but it seems to work fine. didn't even have to use the .local trick

one thing I did before shutting off my computer was turning off firewall, but I kind of doubt that was it

¯_(ツ)_/¯ oh well, it works now

also, thanks to you who've answered, wasn't expecting a reply so quick

Answer (score 0):

Just use name.local, in your example CRISPYSERVER.local (as already mentioned in the comment by Morbius1). I had the same problem with some Windows 10 installations. Some of them can access a Samba share using just the hostname without any problems, others need .local added to the hostname to work. As far as I know, this is not related to enabling or disabling SMB1 functions in Windows 10.